# Youtube API: Unable to add video to playlist

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm trying to add a video to my playlist and got the following response.

```
{
  "code" : 400,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "youtube.playlistItem",
    "message" : "Playlist should use manual sorting to support position.",
    "reason" : "manualSortRequired"
  } ],
  "message" : "Playlist should use manual sorting to support position."
}
```

I went through the youtube API documentation to understand this error.
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/errors#playlistItems_youtube.playlistItems.insert

Here, the description of this error is as following

> The request attempts to set the playlist item's position, but the playlist does not use manual sorting. (For example, playlist items might be sorted by date or popularity.) You can address the error by removing the snippet.position element from the resource that the request is inserting. If you want the playlist item to have a particular position in the list, you need to first update the playlist's Ordering option to Manual in the playlist's settings. This settings can be adjusted in the YouTube Video Manager.

I am unable to see **Ordering** option under [playlist settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RegBb.png) after navigating to YouTube Video Manager. Any way to resolve this error other than removing **snippet.position**.

Comment: Do select the option *Add new videos to top of playlist*.

Comment: Will that not override snippet.position that I send in API call? Like the error description said, setting Ordering to Manual will resolve the error and that makes sense also. I'll try what you've suggested.

Comment: @stvar selecting that option did not resolve the issue that I'm facing. Please advice me further to get a resolution.